# Gravitational constant in lower dimensions

Tags: newtonian-gravity, spacetime, spacetime-dimensions, physical-constants

How does the Newtonian gravitational constant in 2+1 dimensions (let's call it $G_3$) look like?

If $G$ stands for the usual physical Newtonian gravitational constant in 3+1 dimension, so what is the relation between $G$ and $G_3$?

Answer (score 2):

Time isn't a dimension in Newtonian gravity, it's a universal parameter, so $2+1$ dimensions is not exactly appropriate. In 3D (normal Newton), we have:

$$ F = G\frac{Mm}{r^2} $$

meanwhile, in 2D an irrotational field sourced from mass (and coupling to mass linearly) looks like:

$$ F_2 = G_2\frac{Mm}{r} $$

So now you have a problem. $G_2$ [formerly $G_3$] has dimension $[L]^2[M]^{-1}[T]^{-2}$, which differs from $G$ by one inverse power of length.

If you set the forces between 2 equal masses to be the same, you need to pick a length scale:

$$ G\frac{m^2}{r^2} = G_2\frac{m^2}{r} $$

or

$$ G_2 = G/r$$

but what is $r$?.

Another option is to equate the total flux coming out of a mass $M$ and the force on a test mass $m$. At some $r$:

$$\Phi=4\pi r^2 F(r) = 4\pi r^2 G\frac{Mm}{r^2}=4\pi GMm $$

No $r$, so that's good. In 2D:

$$\Phi_2 =2\pi r F(r) = 2\pi r G_2\frac{Mm}{r}=2 \pi G_2Mm $$

Setting those equal give:

$$ G_2 = \frac 1 2 G $$

Looks good. But there is a problem. The fluxes $\Phi$ and $\Phi_2$ have different units, so by equating them we implicitly picked a length scale at which they're equal...even though we factored it out of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answer mentions, Newton's constant is dimensionful so going from $G_4$ to $G_3$ requires a length scale which will depend on the problem.

The main problem I know involving multiple Newton constants is dimensional reduction. This means, the full $d + 1$ dimensional space-time is written as $M_{d - n + 1} \times M^\prime_n$ where $M^\prime_n$ is a compact $n$ dimensional manifold of negligible size. As long as this is a true direct product (not a fibration), a macroscopic observer will see $G_{d - n + 1} =  G_{d + 1} / \mathrm{Vol}(M_n^\prime)$. Taking the Einstein-Hilbert action
\begin{align}
S &= \frac{1}{16\pi G_{d + 1}} \int_{M \times M^\prime} (R_M + R_{M^\prime}) \sqrt{-g} \, dx \\
& \approx \frac{1}{16\pi G_{d + 1}} \int_{M \times M^\prime} R_M \sqrt{-g} \, dx,
\end{align}
we see this by evaluating $n$ of the $d + 1$ integrals and demanding that the overall coefficient is $\frac{1}{16\pi G_{d-n+1}}$.

So to answer your question, if we interpret $3 + 1$ dimensional space as flat $2 + 1$ dimensional space plus a small curled up dimension of radius $r$, then $G_3 = G_4 / 2\pi r$.